# Any way to shorten statements in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to get do the following (after annoyed by the methods in python which do not seem to return the original object):

take the values out of a dictionary `d`, and sort it in reverse order

```
values=d.values()
values.sort(reverse=True)
```

But is there a way to shorten it to one line? In general, I also want to do:

```
weight=range(1,27)
weight.reverse()
```

(I of course could use `range(26,0,-1)`, but if I stick to what I wrote above, is there a way to do it like `weight=range(1,27).reverse()`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, mutating methods in Python return `None`.

There are some built-ins useful to you in this particular case:

```
weight = list(reversed(range(1,27)))
```

The `reversed` and `sorted` builtins return new lists, so you can keep using the old one if you want.

Comment: this does not work!! It returned <listreverseiterator object at 0x10e144490>

Comment: Ah, sorry, if you're using a newer version of Python we might need to force the iteration. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `sorted` function:

```
rvals = sorted(d.values(), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use builtins `sorted` and `reversed`:

```
values = sorted(d.values, reverse=True)

weight = reversed(range(1,27))
```